# How do I swap endian-ness (byte order) of a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, endianness

I am receiving and sending a decimal representation of two little endian numbers. I would like to:

- shift one variable 8 bits left
- OR them
- shift a variable number of bits
- create 2 8 bit numbers representing the first and second half of the 16 bit number.

javascript (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) uses big endian representation when shifting...

endianness is a bit foreign to me (I am only 90 percent sure that my outlined steps are what i want.) so swapping is a bit dizzying. please help! I only really need to know how to swap the order in an efficient manner. (I can only think of using a for loop on a toString() return value)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
function swap16(val) {
    return ((val & 0xFF) << 8)
           | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```

Explanation:

1. Let's say that `val` is, for example, `0xAABB`.
2. Mask `val` to get the LSB by [`&`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0xFF`: result is `0xBB`.
3. [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) that result 8 bits to the left: result is `0xBB00`.
4. [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) `val` 8 bits to the right: result is `0xAA` (the LSB has "dropped off" the right-hand side).
5. Mask that result to get the LSB by [`&`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0xFF`: result is `0xAA`.
6. Combine the results from steps 3 and step 5 by [`|`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) them together:
   `0xBB00 | 0xAA` is `0xBBAA`.

---

```
function swap32(val) {
    return ((val & 0xFF) << 24)
           | ((val & 0xFF00) << 8)
           | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF00)
           | ((val >> 24) & 0xFF);
}
```

Explanation:

1. Let's say that `val` is, for example, `0xAABBCCDD`.
2. Mask `val` to get the LSB by [`&`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0xFF`: result is `0xDD`.
3. [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) that result 24 bits to the left: result is `0xDD000000`.
4. Mask `val` to get the second byte by [`&`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0xFF00`: result is `0xCC00`.
5. [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) that result 8 bits to the left: result is `0xCC0000`.
6. [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) `val` 8 bits to the right: result is `0xAABBCC` (the LSB has "dropped off" the right-hand side).
7. Mask that result to get the second byte by [`&`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0xFF00`: result is `0xBB00`.
8. [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) `val` 24 bits to the right: result is `0xAA` (everything except the MSB has "dropped off" the right-hand side).
9. Mask that result to get the LSB by [`&`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with `0xFF`: result is `0xAA`.
10. Combine the results from steps 3, 5, 7 and 9 by [`|`ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) them together:
    `0xDD000000 | 0xCC0000 | 0xBB00 | 0xAA` is `0xDDCCBBAA`.

Comment: so, this seems to work...is there a plain spoken explanation or should i just take it and run?

Comment: @griotspeak: I've edited to attempt an explanation, although I suspect that it would make more sense for you to read the wikipedia articles on [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) instead.

Comment: ok, this wasn't actually what i wanted, but i think i am simply being unclear. I need a literal reversal of the first 8(or 16?) bits. I think this answer gets me close enough to work it out.

Comment: `function swap8(val) {
    return  ((val &         0x1) << 7) |
            ((val &         0x2) << 5) |
            ((val &         0x4) << 3) |
            ((val &         0x8) << 1) |
            ((val >> 1) &   0x8) |
            ((val >> 3) &   0x4) |
            ((val >> 5) &   0x2) |
            ((val >> 7) &   0x1);
}` was my final solution

Comment: In case this helps anyone, the `swap16()` function alone was not handling signed integers correctly.  I had to combine it with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461204/javascript-unsigned-short-to-signed-short) in order to get everything working correctly: `((((val & 0xFF) << 8) | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF)) << 16) >> 16`

Comment: @whiskeyspider mentioned the sign problem already.  Here's what I ended up with instead:
 
`function swap16(val) {
        var x = ((val & 0xFF) << 8)
               | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF);

        if (x < 0)
            x = (x & 0x7FFF) + 0x8000;

        return x;
    }

    function swap32(val) {

        var x = ((val & 0xFF) << 24)
               | ((val & 0xFF00) << 8)
               | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF00)
               | ((val >> 24) & 0xFF);

        if (x < 0)
            x = (x & 0x7FFFFFFF) + 0x80000000;

        return x;
    }`

Answer (score 10):

Such function can be used to change endianness in js:

```
const changeEndianness = (string) => {
        const result = [];
        let len = string.length - 2;
        while (len >= 0) {
          result.push(string.substr(len, 2));
          len -= 2;
        }
        return result.join('');
}

changeEndianness('AA00FF1234'); /// '3412FF00AA'
```

Comment: Wonderful job using strings!

Answer (score 1):

Use the << (bit shift) operator. Ex: 1 << 2 == 4.

I really think that the underlying implementation of JavaScript will use whatever endianess the platform it is running on is using. Since you cannot directly access memory in JavaScript you won't ever have to worry about how numbers are represented physically in memory. Bit shifting integer values always yield the same result no matter the endianess. You only see a difference when looking at individual bytes in memory using pointers.

Comment: I am literally being given a decimal representation of a little endian number and need to give back a decimal representation of a little ending number. A display is being driven by the binary representation... so it matters.

Comment: i think i see what you were getting at, and i think that in many cases you would be correct. the number i get and give is meant to turn 8 lights on from left to right so i will, essentially, be looking at the individual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner for arrays to swap between big and little endian (and vise versa). The swapping is done using `reverse` on byte level. I guess for large arrays, it is more efficient than looping over scalar swap function.

```js
function swapbyte(x) {
    return new Float64Array(new Int8Array(x.buffer).reverse().buffer).reverse()
}

// Example
buf = new ArrayBuffer(16);        // for 2 float64 numbers
enBig = new Float64Array(buf);
enBig[0] = 3.2073756306779606e-192;
enBig[1] = 2.7604354232023903e+199;

enLittle = swapbyte(enBig)

// two famous numbers are revealed
console.log(enLittle)
// Float64Array [ 6.283185307179586, 2.718281828459045 ]

// swapping again yields the original input
console.log(swapbyte(enLittle))
// Float64Array [ 3.2073756306779606e-192, 2.7604354232023903e+199 ]
```