# Javascript unsigned short to signed short

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
var v = [0xFF, 0xFF];
alert((v[0]<<8) | v[1]);
```

And it alerts 65535 (the max short value).

How can I treat this byte array as a signed short, and get the signed value of this array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the higher bit is the sign:

```
var sign = v[0] & (1 << 7);
var i = ((v[0] & 0x7F) << 8) | v[1];
if (sign) {
    i = -i;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4TQw/1/

---

If you use the [Two's complement](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation:

```
var i = (((v[0] << 8) | v[1]) << 16) >> 16);
```

The 16 bits left shift moves all bits to the left; and the arithmetic 16 bits right shift takes care of the sign while shifting. (Javascript uses 32 bits integers for shift operations.)

http://jsfiddle.net/p4TQw/3/

Comment: Shouldn't [0xFF, 0xFF] be -1 signed? If I do the following code in C#:

`Int16 v = -1; byte[] int16LittleEndian = BitConverter.GetBytes(v); Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ba));` I do get `FF-FF` in return.

Same with `Console.WriteLine( BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[]{0xFF, 0xFF},0));` I get -1;

Comment: Yes, it depends on the convention you use. It's -1 if you use twos complement.

Comment: Updated answer for two's complement