# javascript bitwise operations to modify a rgba value?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I have an integer `4281644543` in javascript. This is an `rgba` value that is actually reversed (`ff34b5ff` but should be `ffb534ff`) when I read it from a Uint32Array view of an ImageData buffer. I don't know why it comes in reversed.

what bitwise operations do I need to perform to get it into `0xffb534` (without the transparency)

thanks!

Comment: "I don't know why it comes in reversed." It sounds like a Big Endian v. Little Endian problem.  I don't know how you are creating your array, but instead of trying to reverse your int, you should see if you can specify the opposite Endian of what you are (implicitly?) using now.

Comment: If you want to hassle with swapping manually, see here: http://www.umsl.edu/~ewm4g2/articles/endian_swap.html

Comment: i'm not building the original ArrayBuffer myself in this case. `var buf32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);` then just iterating buf32...

Comment: found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320439/how-do-i-swap-endian-ness-byte-order-of-a-variable-in-javascript swap32 got close, `>>> 8` finished the job